# convergence of $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the convergence of $ \int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{\cos x}{x} dx $. Could someone check if i did this right?

$\frac{-1}{x} \leq \frac{\cos x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$

$ -\lim_{b \rightarrow 0} \int_b^{2\pi}\frac{1}{x}dx = -\lim_{b \rightarrow 0}\ln (x) |_b^{2\pi} = \lim_{b \rightarrow 0}\ln(b)-\ln(2\pi)=\infty $....... (=divergent)

So by comparison test,
the integral diverges.... Is this fine??

Comment: No. When you get the $\infty$, how do you conclude convergence from that???

Comment: You only show that it is $\leq \infty$ and $\geq -\infty$.

Comment: It diverges, but your proof is wrong. You only proved that the integral is in $[-\infty,\infty]$...

Comment: oops i typed in converges instead of diverge. I meant diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}xdx=\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{\cos x}xdx+\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}xdx$$

The second integral converges because the integrand is continuous in $[\pi/3,2\pi]$, but, since $\cos x\ge1/2$ for $x\in(0,\pi/3)$,
$$\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{\cos x}xdx\ge\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{1/2}xdx=\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac12(\ln(\pi/3)-\ln a)=\infty$$

Therefore, the integral does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

By series expansion of $\cos(x)$, when $x$ is close to $0$, we have $\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} $

So the for the integrand we have $\frac{\cos x}{x} \approx \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{2}$.
Does $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{2} dx$$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{\cos x}{x} dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac {\cos(\frac {2\pi k}{n})}{\frac {2\pi k}{n}}=\lim _{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac {\cos(\frac {2\pi k}{n})}{2\pi k}$. Does this limit converge?